# is there a way to make this program even faster?

Tags: c

is there a way to make this program run faster than 3.8 seconds at 10000000 numbers? this code checks random generated numbers and count and sum the prime numbers amongst them. im using 4 threads that each thread runs on a core. im pretty sure theres some kind of algorithm that's faster than this one for checking primes but i cant find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

long sum=0,count=0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
int numOfRandomNumbers;


int isPrime(int num)
{
int i;

if(num==2||num==3) 
return 1;

if(num%2==0||num%3==0)
return 0;


if((num-1)%6!=0&&((num+1)%6)!=0||((num*num)-1)%8!=0)return 0;


for (i = 5;i*i<=num;i+=6)
{
if (num%i == 0||num%(i+2)==0)return 0;
        
}
return 1;
}

void* prime(void * arg)
{  
int size=*(int*) arg;
int random;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{   
random=rand();
if(isPrime(random))
{ 
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
sum+=random;
count+=1;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
}
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL)!=0)
{
printf("mutix init failed\n"); return 0;
}
if(argc != 3) 
{
printf("Too few arguments ");
printf("USAGE: ./primeCalc <prime pivot> <num of random numbers>");
exit(0);
}
pthread_t tids[4];

int randomPivot = atoi(argv[1]);
numOfRandomNumbers = atoi(argv[2]);
int random = rand();
srand(randomPivot);

long size1 =numOfRandomNumbers/4;
long size2=(2*numOfRandomNumbers/4)-numOfRandomNumbers/4;
long size3=(3*numOfRandomNumbers/4)-(2*numOfRandomNumbers/4);
long size4=numOfRandomNumbers-(3*numOfRandomNumbers/4);

pthread_create(&tids[0], NULL, prime, &size1);
pthread_create(&tids[1], NULL, prime, &size2);
pthread_create(&tids[2], NULL, prime, &size3);
pthread_create(&tids[3], NULL, prime, &size4);

pthread_join(tids[0], NULL);
pthread_join(tids[1], NULL);
pthread_join(tids[2], NULL);
pthread_join(tids[3], NULL);

   
pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
//keep the out format as this!!
printf("%ld,%ld\n",sum,count);

exit(0);
}
```

Comment: first of all, you've got way too many extra checks. `num == 2` or `num == 3` is not **very** likely among the set of numbers you insert there, so better to first check if number <= 3 and handle all special cases inside there.  It is sufficient to check modulo 6 whether it is equal to **1 or 5**, this will take care of **4** of those modulo checks. But what is **most** wrong is to use a **mutex at all**. Instead have each thread have its own sum and count, and after join you'll sum them together - that way you never need to synchronize between the threads when they're running.

Comment: Stop locking the mutex for each increment. Modify the code so each thread completes its own count and reports that once, by putting it into a structure passed to it. (Put the “size” it should test in the structure too, so you are passing one structure, by pointer, with the “size” and space to return the count.) Then adds the counts in the main thread. You do not need a mutex at all.

Comment: If your code is already working and you are merely seeking a performance improvement, then it seems more appropriate to post this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than on Stack Overflow, unless the focus of your question is not supposed to be on your code, but rather on which algorithm to use.

Comment: just tried modifying the code using a struct and not a mutex lock and it turned out 0.1 seconds slower than with the mutex @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes im also looking for another algorithm to make my code faster the algorithm im using is basic and simple

Comment: Note that `rand` is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. This applies to both POSIX and ISO C. Even if it is thread-safe on your platform, it will probably use thread synchronization whenever you generate a new random number. Therefore, for performance reasons, you should probably use a random number generator which supports independant generation of random numbers on several threads without thread synchronization. Unfortunately, ISO C does not offer such a random number generator (not sure about POSIX).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, `rand_r` should AFAIK be POSIX and thread-safe. (tread safety naturally assumes non-concurrent access to each seed variable.) For those who accept glibc extensions, there is also `random_r`.

Comment: Is it really consistent with your intention that the computations of `size1` ... `size4` all produce the same result, +/- differences arising from truncation in the integer divisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two algorithms that come to my mind:

Eratosthenes and OpenMP.

I don't mean a "pure" sieving implementation. But the basic idea that smaller primes help finding bigger ones. No need to divide by every uneven number.

This is what you try with `i+=6` trick. This is good only for lower regions. With an array of found primes the possible divisors are concentrated. Whether you use them as sieve or for trial-division is secondary (a *segmented* sieve is faster than division).

Of cousre with random prime candidates this is less obvious. But with a large number of candidates up to 2 billion (RAND_MAX), an array of primes up to 44000 is enough. Done in no time compared to 3.8 seconds.

(there are also mathematical algorithms, also using some kind of tables - see how fast e.g. `factor` utility is)

As to the concurrency problem:

All this threading incl. counting can be handled by one (and a half) OpenMP lines. Not only easier, but much faster, even probably after you fix the bottleneck.

So this would be a ready-to-use algo for **parallel programming.**

---

Great XY joke: you ask for fast prime algo, but the problem is the interrupted threads.